# Can I select files using checkboxes?

Tags: nautilus

I'm tired of pressing and holding CONTROL key in Ubuntu 11.10 when selecting multiple items, Is there any way to get checkboxes to my documents and directories as in versions of Windows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, you can't make nautilus, the default Ubuntu file manager to use checkboxes. But you can install some other file manager that does.

I don't use alternative file-managers, but in this [article](http://www.tuxarena.com/2011/06/20-file-managers-for-ubuntu/) list 20. Some of then can use checkboxes, although most don't by default. In those that are two-panels, you can usually use space to select more than one file.

There is also check [Marlin](https://launchpad.net/marlin). It's a nautilus fork, aimed at simplicity and ease of use, so they aren't going to use checkboxes, but it's quite popular.

Answer (score 3):

The checkboxes or something similar in [Nautilus](http://live.gnome.org/Nautilus) was planned a long time ago according to wiki: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Ayatana/DoubleClick

But it was not implemented yet.

It is possible out of the box in [Dolphin](http://dolphin.kde.org/) file manager but it's part of KDE, not GNOME/Unity.

Comment: Is a plugin or something like that available for Nautilus?

Comment: None I know of. If you find one please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

Dolphin (KDE) have the feature, but it's implemented differently when you hover a file you have a + or a - to select/deselect the file very productive feature to manage files